# Firm LinkedIn Account No One Remembers Opening

Tags: linkedin, login, delete

My firm has a Linkedin page and no one remembers the username or password.  So, we cannot edit, close, etc.  I am a new administrator and would like to close the profile/account.  How?  Help!!!

Answer (score 0):

There is some guidance here on how to deal with a lost or forgotten password.

[How to Recover Your Forgotten LinkedIn Password](https://www.howtogeek.com/357804/how-to-recover-your-forgotten-linkedin-password/)